# Как отличить тип proxy?

Tags: delphi, proxy

Как с помощью delphi отличить http, socks4, socks5 прокси? Есть идея: подключаться к проксе и переходить на какой-нибудь сайт и при этом смотреть данные запроса, но я не знаю по каким именно данным я должен заставить программу отличить 3 типа прокси.

Comment: Гм... Я всегда считал, что нужно сначала знать, куда подключаться, а потом уже подключаться... А не сначала подключится, а потом уже разбираться - а куда это я подключился)

Comment: Погуглите на тему чтения настроек proxy в операционной системе.

Comment: Можно вначале попытаться подключиться как к http прокси. Если не получилось, то как к sock прокси. Но также можно применять эвристику. К примеру порт 1080 - значит это сокс прокси и вначале стоит попытаться так к ней и подключиться.

Answer (score 1):

### HTTP/s протокол

**HTTP/s Proxy** на сервер мы отправляем только заголовки - *headers*, пример:

```
    GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.domain.com
    Connection: keep-alive
```

### Как работает Socks 4/5?

**Socks 4/5** работает через несколько этапов данных (пакетов), которые вы должны отправить на socks-сервер, прежде чем он сможет заработать.

1. Пакет, включает: версию и способ аутентификации.
2. Пакет, включает: тип подключения (connect / bind), IP:Port (удаленного хоста), протокол через который вы соединяетесь (tcp / udp).
3. На третьем этапе идёт обмен данными, если тип подключения выставлен Bind.

Для ознакомления, советую вам прочитать спецификацию работы Socks5 Протокола [RFC1928](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt).

### Практика и примеры

Для практики и нахождения полного ответа на ваш вопрос, рекомендую вам установить [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/start).
В документации, вы сможете найти нужные для вас примеры (подключиться к любому серверу с помощью socks-proxy или получить http страницу через http/s прокси).

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в софтах, где необходимо указать список проксей используется либо конкретный тип прокси, либо есть возможность указать и те и те как разные списки. Т.е. определение типа ложится на пользователя. И пользователи таких софтов обычно сами нормально справляются.

Если же у вас конкретная задача в этом. То следует предположить тип прокси по порту, например 8080 - http. Попробовать подключиться. Если выйдет- хорошо. Нет - пробуем другой тип.